# Cant configure Global.Asax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to add a scriptmanager in my Global application class on startup so I can use login from toolbox etc. But When I add a Global.Asax file to my project it does not allowe me to use scriptManager. the top of the Global.Asax file looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
```

And that does not feel right, should it not say `Language="C#"` etc?

Anybody know whats going on, or know any other way to load my script so I dont get the `WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking at your `Global.asax.cs`, the code behind file of your `Global.asax`.

Your `Global.asax` should look like

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Namespace.YourApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

While your `Global.asax.cs` contains C# code as in your question.

As answer on your second question: change your web.config. Add this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Yeah I did that, but it just felt like poor coding. But if it makes no difference then Ill keep it that way :)